# Auto return value inference and c++ static typing

Tags: c++, templates, types, generic-programming

In this very interesting use case of auto return value inference(taken from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-inference-in-c-auto-and-decltype/ ):

```
// A generic function which finds minimum of two values 
// return type is type of variable which is minimum 
template <class A, class B>
auto findMin(A a, B b) -> decltype(a < b ? a : b)
{
    return (a < b) ? a : b;
}
```

Wouldnt the type of the return value HAVE to be deduced at run-time because parameters a and b are not constant expressions that can be evaluated at compile-time? I mean, the return value would HAVE to be either A type or B type for every instantiated function call, but it is not clear in *compile-time* which one it is. *a < b ? a : b* is not a constant expression is it?

Wouldn`t this mean c++ is a dynamically typed language. If not, how is the return value of the function deduced at compile time? Are two functions created per instantiation, one that returns A type and another that returns B type? How would that work?

Comment: For given `A` and `B` you'll have only one function with the return type that is a common type of `A` and `B`. C++ is a statically typed language. The type of `cond ? a : b` is always determined at compile time according to [certain rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator).

Comment: @Evg yup, I officially dont understand anything in that part of the website. I must point out Evg that you are a true hero of mine, you are always around to at least try and answer my questions!

Comment: Geeksforgeeks is a bad source, avoid it! The type of `? :` is determined statically (at compile time) according to some [complicated rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator). In short, the compiler picks a type that both operands can be converted to, and uses that same type regardless of the value of the condition.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I completely agree with your assessment of Geeksforgeeks. If you could make your comment into an answer and try to expand a bit more on what you mean for this case of auto return deduction both *in general* and *specifically* for what I ask. I would be happy to accept the answer then.

Comment: When you use template the compiler will build a copy of that template call for each type. Thereby at runtime depending on the type, the template call associated with the particular type gets called.

Comment: @OS2 I believe you mean compile-time, as the template instantiation cant occur at runtime right? *please correct me if im wrong, after all, this is also part of the original question*

Comment: Which function is called is determined at compile time. Templates are not virtuals.

Comment: Use this tool whenever you are working with templates or want to know what compiler is doing: https://cppinsights.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get one function that returns a value of common type of `A` and `B`. C++ is a statically typed language, so the type of `cond ? a : b` should be known at compile time. There are [special rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) to determine that common type. Informally speaking, it is a type that `A` and `B` can be implicitly converted to. If no such type exists, you'll get a compilation error.

For example,

```
int    a = 1;
double b = 2;
auto   c = findMin(a, b);
```

The type of `c` will always be `double`. If `a` is less than `b`, the return value will be `a` converted into `double`, as if `static_cast<double>(a)`.